# Average value of magnitude of vector given expected values of its components... unexpected answer!

Tags: statistics, vectors, mathematical-physics

Tldr;

So basically the question is given a vector $t=(x,y,z)$ and you are given $x,y,z$ are completely random and that they follow boltzman distribution, and that

$ \bar x = 0 $

$\bar |x| = \frac{a}{\sqrt \pi}$

$\bar {x^2} = \frac{a^2}{2}$

can you find $< |t| >$

Actual motivation:

So I was studying some physics, the Kinetic theory and boltzman distribution stuff...

So for gasses, assuming the Kinetic theory, (ie. basically completely random motion)

I derived using the boltzman distribution that:

$<v_x>=0$

$<|v_x|> \ =\frac{a}{\sqrt \pi}$

$<(v_x)^2>\  =a^2/2$

where $<x>$ is ofcourse the mean of $x$. (and $a^2=\frac{2k_BT}{m}$ but that's not important)

So then when it came time for the means of speed, ie $|v|$, (in the following line i am representing speed by $v$

I clearly saw $<v^2> \ = \ <v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2> \ = \ 3<v_x^2> \ = \ \frac{3a^2}{2}$

But then similarly I thought I could find $< v >  \ =\ \sqrt3 \cdot <|v_x|>$

Because $v = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$ but it turns out the actualy answer is

$< v > \ = \ 2 \cdot <|v_x|> \ = \ \frac{2a}{\sqrt \pi}$

(then I saw the correct derivation for this was doing the spherical $4 \pi v^2dv$ thing but it got me thinking if we could derive it without going down that route, but since I haven't really studied much statistics yet, I can't answer that question, so i was hoping someone more experienced could...

So basically the question is given a vector $t=(x,y,z)$ and you are given $x,y,z$ are completely random and that they follow boltzman distribution, and that

$ \bar x = 0 $

$\bar |x| = \frac{a}{\sqrt \pi}$

$\bar {x^2} = \frac{a^2}{2}$

can you find $< |t| >$

Comment: As written, you can't. The result you mentioned, that $\langle v \rangle = 2\langle |v_x| \rangle$ is only true assuming $v_x$, $v_y$, and $v_z$ are independent, which of course you have in the physical situation you mentioned. But the general question you gave has no independence assumption. Indeed, if $x = y = z$ and they all follow the distribution you provided, then $\langle |t| \rangle$ would actually be $\sqrt{3} \langle |x| \rangle$.

Comment: As this example shows, the value of $\langle |t| \rangle$ actually depends on the correlation between $x$, $y$, and $z$. This should also tell you that you can't expect the result with a factor of 2 to be obtained through any straightforward calculation. This isn't really a surprise though. $|t| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$. You simply can't expect to exchange the square root with the expectation in any way. And $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ is *not*, nor just any function of, $|x| + |y| + |z|$, so you can't expect to get expectation from just the expectations of $|x|$, $|y|$, and $|z|$.

Comment: The fastest way I can think of doing this, assuming independence, is to note that, as a distribution on $x$, this is actually a normal distribution with mean 0 and $\sigma = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$. If $x$, $y$, $z$ are independent, then the vector follows a 3d normal distribution, with its direction uniformly distributed across the unit ball, i.e., the density only depends on $r$.

Comment: If you perform the integrals for $\langle |t| \rangle$ and $\langle |z| \rangle$ in spherical coordinates then, you will realize the $r$ integrals are the same between the two and the same holds for the $\phi$ integrals. The $\theta$ integral in $\langle |t| \rangle$ is simply $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi \sin(\theta) d\theta = 1$ and the $\theta$ integral in $\langle |z| \rangle$ adds a term for the projection onto the $z$-axis, i.e., $\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi |\cos(\theta)|\sin(\theta) d\theta = \frac{1}{2}$, so $\langle |z| \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \langle |t| \rangle$.

Comment: @DavidGao wow yeah, that makes sense, you also very clearly explained the intuition for why it isn't so simple... thanks... this was cool